# KeyListener stops working after calling System.gc()

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I've got a program where the user can choose to open a screen by pressing the E key on the keyboard... then this function is used to render that screen:

```
public void render(Graphics g, int x, int y, FontLoader fontLoader){
    g.drawImage(imageManager.getImage("Inventory_Blank"), x, y,null);

    this.length = inventoryItems.size();

    if(length == 0)
        return;
    for(int i = -2; i < 3;i++ ){
        if(selected + i < 0 || selected + i >= length)
            continue;
        drawString(g,inventoryItems.get(selected + i).getName(), (1366 / 2) - 190, (720 / 2) - 7 + i * spacing, true, Color.white, fontLoader.getFont28());
    }
    //not calling this will result in the program lagging and using a lot of memory... 
    System.gc();

}
```

This works fine until the user wants to close the screen again by pressing E again.. which doesn't work... other keys seem to work fine but the E key is not working... why is this happening?

If I don't have the System.gc(); in there the program will use a lot more memory...

Comment: There is very, very, very rarely the need to call `System.gc()` manually. I would even go so far to assume that the problem why you call this is home-made ... Also, that call shouldn't have any side-effect on how the program behaves. It may be, though, that you are using weak references somewhere (which may be why the regular GC process doesn't clean them up regularly).

Comment: I have the feeling you‘re trying to save a Graphics object you didn‘t create.  Graphics objects passed to painting methods are not yours;  they belong to the painting system, and they are only valid for the duration of the paint method to which they are passed.

Comment: Allright.. I'll take a look at this

Comment: I don't think this is the problem as the render method for this class is only called inside the main render method which makes shure everything is rendered... I pass the same graphics I use for rendering everything else